# how to migrate _app to layout nextjs 13?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a problem when using the latest version of next js, I have a custom _app, can this custom be used on the latest version of nextjs?

```
type CustomPage = NextPage & {
  requiresAuth?: boolean;
  redirectUnauthenticatedTo?: string;
};
interface CustomAppProps extends Omit<AppProps, "Component"> {
  Component: CustomPage;
}
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: CustomAppProps) {
  return (
    <>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

```
constTablePage = () => {
   return (
     <MainLayout bgColor="transparent" title="Balance sheet">
       <Balance />
     </MainLayout>
   );
};

TablePage. requiresAuth = true;

export defaultTablePage;
```